# Array formula with index match to return array of matches

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I've been working at this for a bit. I have tried many times different formula combos, using VLOOKUP to using INDEX & MATCH, even with an ARRAYFORMULA.

What I'm attempting to do is match a territory to return a state. Then be able to copy the formula down.

As of now when I copy the formula downwards it can only return the first find in the column.

Where did I go wrong? I'm sure this far too simple and I'm overthinking the entire thing.

I was hoping for something like the following formula to work:

```
=ArrayFormula(index(States,Match(TER 1,Territory,0)))

=ArrayFormula(index($D$3:$D$53,MATCH($B$3,$C$3:$C$53,0)))
```

[image: table using my current index match arrayformula that doesn't work when dragging it down.]

I tried this as well:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,if(C3:C53=J3,D3:D53,"")))
```

But this only returned the array of course.

> AZ, Arizona,ID, Idaho,ME, Maine,NV, Nevada,OH, Ohio,UT, Utah

Comment: Welcome. Please try to avoid cross-posting in the future. 
Also, please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try a query instead. In cell `F4` try the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY($C$3:$D$52,"select D where C='"&G$3&"'"),"")
```

You can even drag the formula from `F3` to the right and all of the rest will auto-fill.

[image: use a query instead of index match or vlookup]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Looks good but when I did it, it didn't work for me. Not sure why. But I did come up with another solution. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!
btw, is it absolutely imperative to wrap it in "IFERROR"?

Comment: The formula **works just fine**. _"Looks good but when I did it, it didn't work for me."_. The only possible way is if you did not copy paste my formula correctly. Please try this: **Select** the formula I gave you. Right click and **copy**. **Paste** in cell `F3`. Practice. **The two formulas are identical, calculating the exact same thing**. As for the link you posted, it is the link in my post. The difference between the 2 posts is accurately [depicted here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/pronunciation/english/tomato). Still. Glad you worked it out :)

Answer (score 1):

So, I was pointed in the right direction by marikamitsos, thank you!
However, I found a slightly different solution.

```
=QUERY($C$3:$D$53,"select D where C='TER 2'")
```

[image: Solution to my question. I needed "QUERY" not "INDEX"]

This article helped a lot > [Google Sheets Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)